# How to enable curl in AppServ

Tags: php, curl

I want to enable curl extension in AppServ. I checked in php.ini that line

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

isn't commented and the php_curl.dll file exists in php/ext. I restarted the computer but when I try to use curl, I get error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in ...
```

How can I enable curl?

Comment: Make sure you are editing the php.ini file that lives in the Apache folder and not the one in the php folder.

Comment: Geez AppServ has not been updated in ages. You need to look at WAMPServer or XAMPP.

Comment: I don't see php.ini file in Apache folder

Comment: Didn't find it in `Apache/bin` :/

Comment: I searched but php.ini is only in php directory.

Comment: DO a `phpinfo()` and look for `Loaded Configuration File` on the first page of the output, that will tell you where Apche is getting its `php.ini` file from

Comment: Ok, I checked php.ini is in `C:\AppServ\php5.3.28\php.ini`. In this file php_curl.dll isn't commented and it should work, but it isn't.

Comment: Ok in that case make sure `libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll` are available in the Apache/bin folder

Comment: This files aren't in `Apache/bin`, but they're in `php5.3.28`

Comment: Yup: But they need to be in the Apache/bin as well

Comment: Ok, I copied it. Do I need to restart now?

Comment: Yes of course, restart Apache

Comment: Now I think it works. Thanks a lot! How can I repay your help? :)

Comment: Hugh amounts of money would be very nice. Thanks you.